# How to make stylesheet_link_tag to render css from a local drive in which the server is running

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to make stylesheet_link_tag to render css from a local drive in which the server is running?
I am trying to use <%=stylesheet_link_tag "file:///C:/aaaa.css"%> 
But the style is not being applied in the page.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. The CSS file must be available to your Rails Server, so it can be downloaded by your browser.

Depending on which version of rails your using:

Rails <= 3.0: `public/stylesheets/aaaa.css`
Rails >= 3.1: `app/assets/stylesheets/aaaa.css`

Then use this in your layout:

```
stylesheet_link_tag 'aaaa'
```